# invalid byte 1 of 1-byte utf-8 sequence error

Tags: android

I have build.xml and when i try to use ant

```
d:\project_foldr\ant all
```

in cmd,I get

```
BUILD FAILED
    Error reading project file d:\project_foldr\build.xml: Invalid byte 1 of 1-byte utf-8 sequence.
```

I googled this and got that the document isn't actually encoded in UTF-8,How can I rectify this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a suitable editor, e.g. [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org). Here you can convert between several encodings. It seems that your file contains some 'special' characters (non ascii, like "ü") and is saved in some local encoding and not as utf8. Make sure that in your editor utf8 is the default encoding for all Java/ant files.